# WebSocket, как отправить сообщение в канал определенного события?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Задача состоит в том, чтобы зарегестрировать несколько обработчиков на определенные события.
Например: `create, update, remove`. После чего получить возможность отправлять сообщения только в определенный канал. Например, чтобы в случае, когда сообщение предназначено для `create`, остальные его не получали. Нужно что-то на подобии: socket.emit("create", "message").

В socket io есть метод emit. В redis есть подобные события.

Однако, у меня нет необходимости использовать socket io, он будет излишен в текущем проекте.

Взял https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Сообщение там отправить можно, можно и обработчик создать (он упоминается в документации github).

Но как привязать сообщение на определенное событие?

Comment: создавайте свой протокол поверх websocket. например гоните все данные в json со структурой `{ "event": "create", "data": "message" }` и пишите свой механизм регистрации обработчиков на события, которые будете вызывать при получении сообщений через сокет

Comment: Понятно... Взял socket io.